# Find the match among the same keys in an multi-nested array?

Tags: php, php-5.3, array-difference, array-key-exists

Following up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036969/find-a-key-exists-in-the-sub-keys-of-an-array), I have a further problem - I have two same sub keys, but they have different combination of array in their `variant` key, for instance,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [quantity_request] => 1
                    [time_created] => 1339688613
                    [variant] => Array
                        (
                         [0] => x
                         [1] => y
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [quantity_request] => 1
                    [time_created] => 1339688631
                    [variant] => Array
                        (
                         [0] => x
                         [1] => z
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [quantity_request] => 1
                    [time_created] => 1339688959
                    [variant] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

so, how can I find the match of this item,

```
    [b] => Array
                        (
                            [quantity_request] => 1
                            [time_created] => 1339688631
                            [variant] => Array
                                (
                                 [0] => x
                                 [1] => z
                                )

                        )

    function get_letter($letter,$array)
        {
            foreach($this->content as $k => $v)
            {
                if(array_key_exists($letter, $v))
                {
                    return $k;

                }
            }
            return false;

        }

list($key,$different) = get_letter('b',array("x","z")); // return 1
```

I want the result like this if there is a match,

```
2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain your question with more detail? Why should the result be `2,0`?

Comment: I want to find the key of the toppest level which is `2` actually (I edited my question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add:

```
if ($v['variant'] == $array)
```

inside your `if` statement to compare the `variant` array with the one passed as an argument.

```
function get_letter($letter, $array)
{
     foreach($this->content as $k => $v)
     {
          if(array_key_exists($letter, $v))
          {
               if ($v['variant'] == $array)
                   return $k;
          }
     }

     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are compared value-to-value, so this should work just fine.

```
$key = array_search($needle, $haystack);
```

where `$needle` is the array you want to find the key for.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types